# Using <g:helpBallon> - Tag in Templates

Tags: grails

is it possible to use <g:helpBallon> - Tag within a template? 
When I insert it, i got a blank page ...
Where have I to include the javascript?

Thanks in advance !
Ronny

Comment: Took me 20 Seconds to get that you mean grails (by looking at your tags)

Answer (score 0):

You need `<g:helpBalloons/>` in your layout's header.

Here are some good getting started docs:

http://www.grails.org/plugin/help-balloons